# Problem with logo in a footer of Moodle website

Tags: html, moodle, moodle-api

I replaced Moodle logo with a logo of my web place keeping the same file name and file size and the new logo shows up when I run my website in Firefox or Edge, but the logo doesn't show up in Chrome, Brave and maybe other web browsers.
What I did:

- I put my logo in this file: /pix/moodlelogo_grayhat.png
- I changed logo link in: /lib/outputrenderers.php
  If someone wants to take a look, [this is my website](https://enastava.me).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Links to a site aren't considered adequate on SO. Please post your HTML snippet and any relevant CSS here, in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your theme's markup doesn't contain the filename extension. For some reason (either server configuration or file problems) the browser thinks that the image is an SVG file.

[image]

The best solution may be to modify the theme to add `.png` to the markup. If the filename is dynamically injected via template code you may just need to rename the file with the extension present.

Comment: I guess that the filename is injected dynamically. I can't rename the file with the extension here because it doesn't work:

`code`'<img src="' . $this->image_url('moodlelogo_grayhat') . '" alt="'.get_string('moodlelogo').'" /></a>`code`

Comment: There are also both files at the same location - .png and .svg

Answer (score 0):

Based on what @isherwood said, I fixed this problem.
I edited outputrenderers.php (/lib folder) where the filename was dynamically injected from.

It was:

```
<img src="' . $this->image_url('moodlelogo_grayhat') . '" alt="'.get_string('moodlelogo').'" /></a>
```

I put instead:

```
<a title="MyWeb" href="https://mywebplace.com/">
 <img alt="MyWeb" src="https://mywebplace.com/pix/moodlelogo_grayhat.png"></a>
```

Thanks.